# Scrapy XPath output different to a browser

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I can't figure out what's wrong here. I'm using Scrapy to get data off a website that basically looks like this:

```
        <li class="foo">
            <span class="date1">20 hours ago</span>

            <span class="date2">
                <span class="bar">26-06-2015</span>
            </span>
        </li>
```

Now, if I select the first span using XPath in my browser like `$x('//li/span[1]//text()')`, then I get the expected output `'20 hours ago'` and when I use the same expression in Scrapy, the result is the same.

However, when I alter the expression to take the second date (`class="bar"`), hence `$x('//li/span[2]//text()')` or `$x('//li/span[1]/span[1]/text()')` it works in the browser but not within Scrapy (the result in an empty array).

What could be the problem, please?

Comment: What would be the output of `response.xpath("//li[@class='foo']").extract()`?

Comment: @alecxe `"<li class=\"foo\">\n                    \n                    <span class=\"date1\">20 hours ago</span>\n                    \n                    \n                </li>"` (Plus a whole bunch of spaces between those newline characters that SE leaves out.)

Comment: Thanks. And here is your answer - there is no element with `data2` class. It is probably constructed with the help of js being executed in the browser. Can you share the actual URL your are testing against?

Comment: @alecxe Sure thing, but I though of that – it's true that the website uses JS to pop up the data in that span but when I turned JS off in the browser and reloaded the page, it was still there. Anyway, if you're willing to take a look, [here's the website](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?p=57353255). Have a look at line 1892 or search for `datestamp` (`bar` in my minimal example).

Comment: Thanks, a follow-up question: are you logged in to the forum while being in the browser?

Comment: @alecxe That was it, thank you very much! It didn't even cross my mind that this basic feature is only accessible to logged in users… Feel free to add that as an answer and I shall accept it.

Comment: `//li/span[2]/span/text()` or `//li//span[@class="bar"]/text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to label this question as answered after almost three years, I merely didn't realise the information I was trying to scrape was only available to users who were logged in.